# Lucene - escape word?

Tags: lucene

I am playing with lucene for a location search off of a city and state, and everything is going pretty well.  the query parser fails when i pass it "state:OR" and disreguards "state:or"

Is there a way to tell the searcher/query parser that I am indeed searching for "OR" ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that if you put OR inside quotes it will not be treated as an operator - i.e.

state:"OR"